# can not update when using xcode with subversion

Tags: ios, xcode

I have some problems when using xcode with subversion:

1: when I right click the sourc file, and choose "Source Control -> Update Selected Files...",  it will show "the operation could not be performed because the selection is invalid". Sometimes it's ok, but most of the time, it will show the above message.
When in Organizer, it's no problem.

2: if the update dialog appears(the dialog that can choose which file to update), The "Update" button is disabled, or it has no effect when clicked, even if I uncheck the conflict files.
When in Organizer, the same problem happens.

Does anyone give me some help?